# Prevent images loading from cache after replacing image in FTP

Tags: image, caching, adobe, refresh, muse

I designed a couple of websites for clients using Adobe Muse. They have specials that change regularly, and I upload them as images when they do change. After I replace the image with a new one (through FTP), the sites show the OLD image until I refresh. This is a common complaint with these clients as it appears on their end that nothing was replaced at all.

Is there a way to have the browser automatically show the new image without loading the cached copy? Can I accomplish this in Muse or do I need to rebuild the whole thing with PHP/HTML?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Solved. See answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the browser caches requests by url.  you could probabaly append the update timestamp onto the URL as a parameter.  Then when the update time changes the url would be different and the browser should pull the updated image.

Comment: This would probably work, but I'm ideally looking to find some functionality for this within Adobe Muse.

Comment: I used your answer to figure a solution. See below. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about Adobe Muse, so i couldn't really offer any other advice.  I'm glad you figured out a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out, coming from @ChrisThompson 's answer. Using JavaScript, I created a date variable and then changed the src of the image with getElementById. I put this code manually into the exported HTML document from Muse. Not the most graceful solution, but it shouldn't become an issue until I have to change the design of that particular page.

In the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var pageTime = d.getTime();
</script>
```

Just beneath the original img element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("u696").href = "images/coupons.png?" + pageTime;
    document.getElementById("u696_img").src = "images/coupons.jpg?" + pageTime;
</script>
```

(There is a href and a src because the image on the page links to a larger version, so both needed this treatment. u696 is the id that Muse gave to these particular elements.)